# How to add HTML5 'required' attribute to wp_dropdown_categories() without JavaScripts?

Tags: categories, taxonomy, dropdown

I'm using `wp_dropdown_categories()` for populating `<select>` field with custom taxonomy terms.

If the code is like below:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'show_option_none'   => __( 'Select one', 'text-domain' ),
    'taxonomy'           => 'my_tax',
    'id'                 => 'tax-type',
    'echo'               => 1,
);
wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
```

It's working just fine. I can make the field mandatory with jQuery:

```
$('#tax-type option:first').val(null);
$('#tax-type').attr('required', true);
```

It's working too. But, I want to make the field mandatory without JavaScripts. I tried adding the following by making the `'echo'` to `0`:

```
$new = array();
$new['required'] = true;
$mrg = array_merge($args, $new);
var_dump($mrg); //outputs 'required'=>1
$dd = wp_dropdown_categories( $mrg );
echo $dd;
```

I can also understand why it's not working. But is there a way I can achieve that without JavaScripts? Any filter? Please don't just say:

> *copy from the core and make your new one with that option.*

And my second question is: Why the none_option's value is `-1`? Why not it's a `''` (null)?

Comment: IMHO it is worth opening a trac ticket to have the option for a "Required" as part of the API

Comment: I'll open one tonight inshALLAH.

Comment: @MarkKaplun https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31909

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to apply the `required` attribute every time you use `wp_categories_dropdown`, use `wp_dropdown_cats` filter as suggested in other answers:

```
add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_cats', 'wp_dropdown_categories_required' );
function wp_dropdown_categories_required( $output ){
    return preg_replace( 
        '^' . preg_quote( '<select ' ) . '^', 
        '<select required ', 
        $output 
    );
}
```

If you want to apply the `required` attribute only in especific situations, you can use `wp_dropdown_categories` with `echo` argument set to `false`, introduce the `required` attribute in the returned string and then `echo`:

```
$args = array(
    'show_option_none'   => __( 'Select one', 'text-domain' ),
    'taxonomy'           => 'my_tax',
    'id'                 => 'tax-type',
    'echo'               => false,
);

$cat_dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );

$cat_dropdown = preg_replace( 
        '^' . preg_quote( '<select ' ) . '^', 
        '<select required ', 
        $cat_dropdown
    );

echo $cat_dropdown;
```

Or maybe better, apply the filter combined with a custom `required` attribute:

```
add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_cats', 'wp_dropdown_categories_required', 10, 2 );
function wp_dropdown_categories_required( $output, $args ){

    if( isset( $args['required'] ) && $args['required'] ) {

       $output = preg_replace( 
            '^' . preg_quote( '<select ' ) . '^', 
            '<select required ', 
            $output 
       );

    }

    return $output;

}
```

And then use `wp_dropdown_categories` like this:

```
$args = array(
    'show_option_none'   => __( 'Select one', 'text-domain' ),
    'taxonomy'           => 'my_tax',
    'id'                 => 'tax-type',
    'required'           => true,
);

wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
```

About the second question, you should know that there is a "one question per thread" rule. Remember that for future questions. Than being said, `-1` is the default value for `option_none_value` argument. This argument was not documented (now it is, I've added it to [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories#Arguments)). You can override it as follow:

```
$args = array(
    'show_option_none'   => __( 'Select one', 'text-domain' ),
    'option_none_value'  => NULL,
    'taxonomy'           => 'my_tax',
    'id'                 => 'tax-type',
    'echo'               => false
);
```

PD: I'm not sure if `NULL` is a valid value for a `option` in a `select` element. Also, note that `''` (empty string) is not the same that `NULL`. An empty string is a string data type with zero length; `NULL` is not any date type and has not data properties, it is nothing.

Comment: **THE** answer. The ultimate demand was an empty check and I can do with your answer using `''` there. Thank you. And sure, one question per thread - I'll remember from the next. :)

Comment: I used `NULL` because you requested it in the question. I've added a little explanation (very basic) about `NULL` and `''` (empty string).

Answer (score 4):

## Update: WordPress 4.6

As from WordPress 4.6 we can add a 'required' attribute directly to [`wp_dropdown_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/).

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'show_option_none'   => __( 'Select one', 'text-domain' ),
    'taxonomy'           => 'my_tax',
    'id'                 => 'tax-type',
    'echo'               => 1,
    'required'           => true
);
wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
```

**Source:** [Core Tract Ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31909)

Answer (score 1):

There's a filter - `wp_dropdown_cats` (not documented anywhere as far as I know.)

It gives you two parameters, the HTML string and an array of the arguments supplied to `wp_dropdown_categories`, and you need to return the new HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - you're the first mentioning about the filter. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look into the function in *wp-includes/category-template.php* you will see, there is no option for 'required' build in. So we have to choose another way since `$args['required']` doesn't work - as you know.

We find the filter `'wp_dropdown_cats'`, which provides us with the output just before the function returns this output. So we could work with this filter and alter
`"<select "` to `"<select required "`:

```
add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_cats', 'wp_dropdown_categories_required' );
function wp_dropdown_categories_required( $output ){
    return preg_replace( 
        '^' . preg_quote( '<select ' ) . '^', 
        '<select required ', 
        $output 
    );
}
```

Regarding your second question:

> Why the none_option's value is -1? Why not it's a '' (null)?

This is the standard value, which the function adds to the "none"-option. You can change this value with $args['option_none_value']. So for example:

```
$args = array(
    'show_option_none'   => 'test',
    'option_none_value'  => 'x'
);
wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories

If you want to add the "required"-Attribute just to a specific select-field, you could add yourself a 'required'-Attribute, which you check in the filter:

```
    function show_pages(){
    $args = array(
        'show_option_none'   => 'test',
        'option_none_value'  => 'x',
        'required'           => true
    );
    wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
    }

    add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_cats', 'wp_dropdown_categories_required', 10, 2 );
    function wp_dropdown_categories_required( $output, $args ){
        if( ! isset( $args['required'] ) || $args['required'] != true )
            return $output;

        return preg_replace( 
            '^' . preg_quote( '<select ' ) . '^', 
            '<select required ', 
            $output 
        );
    }
```

All the best.

Comment: Nope, it's producing `-1` - screenshot: http://prntscr.com/6pso22 . And how to add the `required` into specific fields not all the dropdowns?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're the first with a code block. But you may agree that @cybmeta's answer is complete. BTW thanks a lot and +1 for your effort.

Comment: haha, yes a bit late. Anyway, edited my answer to match your question in a better way :)

Comment: [Edited](http://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=Function_Reference%2Fwp_dropdown_categories&action=historysubmit&diff=150585&oldid=150584) and added `option_none_value` in default values. Thanks to @cybmeta for [his edit](http://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=Function_Reference%2Fwp_dropdown_categories&action=historysubmit&diff=150584&oldid=147919) too.