# How to provide value for 'selected' on wp_dropdown_categories() for 'multiple' options

Tags: categories, dropdown

I'm using `wp_dropdown_categories()` with `multiple="multiple"` [in this way](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/183292/22728), bypassing WordPress core. Till now (WP 4.4.1) doesn't support `multiple` on that select field. <sup>([Core Ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31909))</sup>

I'm struggling with the `selected` parameter. How can I pass multiple values so that the `selected` parameter can understand which multiple options to be selected?

I think it's possible only by writing own function supporting array values for selection.

Any easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @markkaplun. I solved it writing my own:

```
<?php
/**
 * Dropdown for 'my_tax'
 * @since  1.0.0 Using wp_dropdown_categories().
 * @since  2.0.3 Custom code, as wp_dropdown_categories() doesn't provide
 *               'selected' field for multiple="multiple"
 */
$my_tax_terms = get_terms( 'my_tax', array('hide_empty'=>false) );
echo '<select required multiple="multiple" name="my_tax[]" id="my-tax" class="postform">';
    foreach ($my_tax_terms as $tax_term) {
        $selected = !empty($_POST['my_tax']) && in_array( $tax_term->term_id, $_POST['my_tax'] ) ? ' selected="selected" ' : '';
        echo '<option value="'. $tax_term->term_id .'" '. $selected .'>'. $tax_term->name .'</option>';
    }
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: [Standard solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/261094/105285)

Answer (score 1):

As the core tickets (for example https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16734) say the point of the api is to provide a dropdown and not a multiselect. IIRC in the quick edit of posts no API is being used for the category and tags multiselct.

In other words, just ignore the API and write your own.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do a similar thing as described in that answer and filter the output from `wp_category_dropdown` using `wp_dropdown_cats`, but for the options instead of select eg.

```
add_filter('wp_dropdown_cats', 'wp_dropdown_categories_multiselect');
function wp_dropdown_categories_multiselect($output) {
    $valuekey = 'valuekey'; // set to 'name' argument passed
    // check this is the correct dropdown
    if (strstr($output,'name="'.$valuekey.'"')) {
        // add multiple to select (you may already have this)
        $output = str_replace('<select ','<select multiple ',$output);
        // add square brackets to the name key
        $output = str_replace('name="'.$valuekey.'"','name="'.$valuekey.'[]"',$output);
        $selectedvalues = get_option($valuekey);
        // make sure there is a selected value
        if (count($selectedvalues) > 0) {
            // loop through the selected values
            foreach ($selectedvalues as $value) {
                // add the selected to each selected value
                $output = str_replace( 
                    '<option value="'.$value.'"',
                    '<option value="'.$value.'" selected="selected"',
                    $output 
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Note: assumes you are saving the value as an array of selected values to the options table. eg.

```
$valuekey = 'valuekey';
if (isset($_REQUEST[$valuekey])) {
    $selectedvalues = $_REQUEST[$valuekey];
    if (!add_option('valuekey',$selectedvalues)) {
        update_option('valuekey',$selectedvalues);
    }
}
```

Of course with the use of `str_replace` the first value of each occurrence would have to exactly match to the output, so there may be some debugging required there to get this to work.

Comment: You have a serious syntax issue according to the syntax highlighter ;-)

Comment: one missing quote mark, not so serious but still fatal, lol